# Вывод слов, состоящих из первых и последних букв текста

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача такова: написать прогу на WinForm, чтобы напечатать  слова, которые состоят с первых и последних букв  (но не цифр) всех слов текста.

На форме в первый textbox (назван num1), я ввожу текст, потом нажимаю button - вывести, и во втором textbox (назван num2), должен быть результат. Вот часть кода (обработчик нажатия button).

Как правильно вывести результат?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str;
            str = num1.Text;
            string sb = "";
             foreach (string val in str.Split(' '))
             {
                 foreach (char ch in val)
                 {
                     if (Char.IsDigit(val[0]))
                     { }
                     else
                     { sb += val[0];}

                     if (Char.IsDigit(val[val.Length - 1]))
                     { }
                     else
                     { sb += val[val.Length-1]; }
                 }
            }
             num2.Text(sb); **ошибка вывода**

        }
```

Comment: Text это свойство, а не метод: num2.Text = sb;

И текст ошибки тоже желательно приводить.

Comment: Сделайте меня развидеть этот if { } else { something; }. Интересно, так где-то учат писать или человек собственным умом дошел?

Вот еще информация к размышлению - https://clck.ru/9SkGp

Я уж молчу, что строки в дотнете иммутабельны... На фоне всего остального это такая мелочь.

Задание вообще непонятно. Допустим, есть текст "Маша ела кашу". Первые буквы слов - М, е, к. Последние - а, а, у. Надо вывести все слова, которые состоят только из этих букв. Так? Кстати, в данном случае таких слов вообще нет. В "Маша" есть 'ш', в "ела" - 'л', в "кашу" - 'ш'. А "Мекка" и "кума" удовлетворяли бы условию

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не очень понятный. Если надо было выводить слова из полученных букв, то не хватает словаря по которому можно пройтись и найти нужные слова.

Если просто надо вывести буквы в num2.Text, то вот простое решение:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = num1.Text
            .Split()
            .SelectMany(w => new char[] { w.First(), w.Last() })
            .Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c));
        num2.Text = String.Concat(result);
    }
```